# How to insert line break + tabulation in a Nano text editor?

Tags: nano

Replace `<br>` with a line break in Nano. Tried to **Atom** - dies. I Inserted `\n`, `\r`, `\n\r` but, inserted simply as characters. How do I insert a **line break** + **taboolation**? File is `.Html`.

Example:

```
Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello
```

Result:

```
Hello
   Hello
   Hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like `vim` instead of `nano`.

Open the file using vim and press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then type:

```
:s/<br>/\r\t/g
```

and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>

To save the file and exit, run the following sequence of keys which will ***write*** the file (save) and ***quit*** `vim`:

press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then type:

```
:wq
```

and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>

[Click here to view a related question which explains why this cannot be done using nano.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959610/nano-insert-newline-in-search-and-replace)

---

Alternatively, you could use `sed` to edit the file.

Here is an example:

I will use the example filename "HELLO":

```
sed -i 's/<br>/\n\t/g' HELLO
```

Furthermore, if you want to create a file instead, you can run the following command to create the file by piping the output of `sed` to a file using `tee`:

```
echo 'Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello' | sed 's/<br>/\n\t/g' | tee HELLO
```